# Simplifying code - multiples of x (NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I currently have a piece of coding which I want to simplify. Essentially I want a procedure to happen every time a custom value equals a multiple of x. The way I have done it so far is to write a separate line of code for each multiple up to 35, however I want it to go much higher than 35, the way it is so far is messy, time consuming and takes up space! I need some piece of coding that accounts for any whole integer within a range (I think!).

Currently I have this (I have only shown you the first 5 lines so as not to fill up the thread, but I currently go up to 35):

```
to fly-emergence

  ask flies
  [if (age >= (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 1) - 0.5)) and (age < (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 1) + 0.5)) [hatch 1 [set age 0]]]  
    ask flies
  [if (age >= (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 2) - 0.5)) and (age < (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 2) + 0.5)) [hatch 1 [set age 0]]]  
    ask flies
  [if (age >= (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 3) - 0.5)) and (age < (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 3) + 0.5)) [hatch 1 [set age 0]]]  
    ask flies
  [if (age >= (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 4) - 0.5)) and (age < (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 4) + 0.5)) [hatch 1 [set age 0]]]  
    ask flies
  [if (age >= (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 5) - 0.5)) and (age < (((fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) * 5) + 0.5)) [hatch 1 [set age 0]]]  

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `mod` primitive:

```
to fly-emergence
  ask flies [
    if (round age) mod (fly-life-expectancy / fly-life-progeny) = 0
      [ hatch 1 [ set age 0 ] ]
  ]
end
```

I'm not absolutely sure I've matched your code exactly... but the basic ideas are, use `mod` to make something periodic, and use `round` to avoid the  "-0.5 to 0.5" part of the check.

Comment: Apologies, I still don't understand the "mod" function. Thanks for the rounding function though. I just need something to act as any whole integer or any multiple of an integer.

Comment: if `a mod b = 0` then a is an exact multiple of b.